# View each result of a query with Jinja , python

Tags: python, html, mongodb, jinja2

After a query is executed in my collection named 'patients' in mongodb: I have this code as a result that is named `patient_doc`:

```
{ "_id" : "5576ee2e1a6d6d0d9b879095", "date_of_birth" : "29/06/2015", "diagnosis" : "Mamografia", "doctor_id" : "554b6e791a6d6d34cc3272f7", "name" : "Xona", "sex" : "Female", "surname" : "Krasniqi" }
{ "_id" : "5576ee2e1a6d6d0d9b879095", "date_of_birth" : "29/06/2015", "diagnosis" : "Ekografia", "doctor_id" : "554b6e791a6d6d34cc3272f7", "name" : "John", "sex" : "Male", "surname" : "Esma" }
```

I render a template that contains a table:

```
return render_template('patient-record.html', patient_doc=doc)
```

In the browser i have only one patient displayed , how can i use jinja syntax to view all results. I mean how can I do a loop that will display data for each patient in my case. I tried `{% for patient_doc in patient_doc %}` but no result.

Html file named patient-record.html contain this code:

```
   <table class="patient-view-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="property-name-col">Name:</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient_doc.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="property-name-col">Surname:</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient_doc.surname }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="property-name-col">Sex:</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient_doc.sex }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="property-name-col">Date of birth:</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{patient_doc.date_of_birth}}      
  </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="property-name-col">Diagnosis:</td>
    <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient_doc.diagnosis }}</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Can any body help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't duplicate the variable name `patient_doc` in the for loop.

Do like this:

`{% for patient in patient_doc %}`

Example:

```
<table class="patient-view-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
      <th>Date of birth</th>
      <th>Diagnosis</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for patient in patient_doc %}
    <tr>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.name }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.surname }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.sex }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.date_of_birth }}</td>    
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.diagnosis }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if the result is a list i think the name of the variable should be `patients_doc`

```
return render_template('patient-record.html', patients_doc=doc)
```

Example:

```
<table class="patient-view-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
      <th>Date of birth</th>
      <th>Diagnosis</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for patient in patients_doc %}
    <tr>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.name }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.surname }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.sex }}</td>
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.date_of_birth }}</td>    
      <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.diagnosis }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @VictorLean first thanks for your answer. I want  something dynamic because I can add and delete patients, and then if I   add for example 100 patients how can i  do 100 tables?

Comment: @Egzona Just edited the example, just use the ```<thead>``` and ```<tbody>``` tags.